# Invoice data copy to another sheet but not the formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros

I see a lot of questions here on this site but not sure if mine has been answered. I found a macro and made it work for what i need except for one thing. When it copies my data over from sheet 1 to sheet 2 it brings in blank cells. Due to the formulas that are in the blank cells on sheet1. I just want what lines that have text filled in not the ones with the formulas.

```
Sub Button2_Click()
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim i As Long
  Dim a As Long
  Dim rng_dest As Range
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  i = 1
  Set rng_dest = Sheets("Invoice data").Range("C:J")
  ' Find first empty row in columns D:G on sheet Invoice data
  Do Until WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng_dest.Rows(i)) = 0
    i = i + 1
  Loop
  'Copy range B16:I38 on sheet Invoice to Variant array
  Set rng = Sheets("Invoice").Range("A16:H30")
  ' Copy rows containing values to sheet Invoice data
  For a = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng.Rows(a)) <> 0 Then
      rng_dest.Rows(i).Value = rng.Rows(a).Value
      'Copy Invoice number
      Sheets("Invoice data").Range("A" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("G3").Value
      'Copy Date
      Sheets("Invoice data").Range("B" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("F2").Value
      'Copy Customer name
      Sheets("Invoice data").Range("k" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("B8").Value
      'Copy Customer Address
      Sheets("Invoice data").Range("l" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("B9").Value
      'Copy Customer City,state
      Sheets("Invoice data").Range("m" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("B10").Value
      'Copy Customer Phone
      Sheets("Invoice data").Range("n" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("B11").Value
      'Copy Customer Email
      Sheets("Invoice data").Range("o" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("B12").Value
      i = i + 1
    End If
  Next a
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Check the `Range.HasFormula` property and skip those where that property is `True`. You will end up with blank entries doing the loop the way you are.

Comment: thank you for answering, but i do not know macros. So where do i add that or replace that?

Comment: @SmileyFtW - I think the OP does not want cells with formulas that result in `""`; only the ones with formulas that result in a full text strings not zero-length strings. The invoice is probably set up with a number of blank lines (zero-length strings) that are filled in auto-magically when other data has been input.

Comment: If my assumptions are correct, then this question is impossible to answer without knowing what causes the formulas to return values instead of zero-length strings. However, I can tell you that `WorksheetFunction.CountA` is the wrong approach since it counts cells with `""`.

Comment: this macro does not add the blanks cells when text is enter manually. When i have formula fill in the cells then it adds the blank lines in the result. i am not sure if that answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

If your question has correctly been understood by me, simply adding an extra conditional "If" for the source value like code below should solve the problem. If this does not work, please let me know, so we can work on another fix together.

```
Sub Button2_Click()
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim i As Long
  Dim a As Long
  Dim rng_dest As Range
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  i = 1
  Set rng_dest = Sheets("Invoice data").Range("C:J")
  ' Find first empty row in columns D:G on sheet Invoice data
  Do Until WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng_dest.Rows(i)) = 0
    i = i + 1
  Loop
  'Copy range B16:I38 on sheet Invoice to Variant array
  Set rng = Sheets("Invoice").Range("A16:H30")
  ' Copy rows containing values to sheet Invoice data
  For a = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng.Rows(a)) <> 0 Then
      If rng.Rows(a).FormulaR1C1 <> "" then
        rng_dest.Rows(i).Value = rng.Rows(a).Value
        'Copy Invoice number
        Sheets("Invoice data").Range("A" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("G3").Value
        'Copy Date
        Sheets("Invoice data").Range("B" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("F2").Value
        'Copy Customer name
        Sheets("Invoice data").Range("k" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("B8").Value
        'Copy Customer Address
        Sheets("Invoice data").Range("l" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("B9").Value
        'Copy Customer City,state
        Sheets("Invoice data").Range("m" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("B10").Value
        'Copy Customer Phone
        Sheets("Invoice data").Range("n" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("B11").Value
        'Copy Customer Email
        Sheets("Invoice data").Range("o" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("B12").Value
        i = i + 1
      End If
    End If
  Next a
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```